# How to enable gzip compression for static Rack sites on Heroku Cedar?

Tags: heroku, gzip, rack, deflate, cedar

Following the [Creating Static Sites in Ruby with Rack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby) article, I get a static site on Heroku with a `config.ru` that looks like this:

```rb
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

When I run YSlow over the result, it reported none of the files were gzipped. What do I do to compress both the assets and the `public/index.html`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my [previous experience](https://github.com/awendt/recharge/blob/master/config.ru#L14) with Sprockets, Sinatra, and the `Rack::Deflater`, I was pretty sure I was just another `use Rack::Deflater` line away from what I wanted.

I changed the `config.ru` to this:

```rb
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"
use Rack::Deflater

run lambda # ...same as in the question
```

and I was able to verify that responses were sent gzipped:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:9292 | file -
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data
```

but not for static assets under `/css`, `/js`, or `/images`:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:9292/css/bootstrap.min.css | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII English text, with very long lines
```

And that's when I realized this was a standard middleware stack—Rack::Static [intercepts](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/static.rb#L117) the call to static files and thus skips the following stack! That's why it worked for `public/index.html` but not for assets.

The following `config.ru` worked (note that `use Rack::Deflater` now precedes `use Rack::Static`):

```rb
use Rack::Deflater
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Verified with:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://localhost:9292/css/bootstrap.min.css | file -
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, from Unix
```